# Dynamically passing bean to rich:popupPanel

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a base class, which is normal Java class. Three subclasses extend it which are `@ViewScoped` beans. There's a `facelet` using a dynamic variable. I have three `xhtml` pages which use this facelets with the three beans viz. `bean1, bean2 and bean3` which are dynamically included in a `rich:tab` component on a main page.
So far so good. But on every page there are a few popups which should refer to the current bean. And since those popups need `form` tag inside them, I have included them outside the main page's form tags in order to avoid nested `form` tags. Now I want the popup to refer to current bean (bean1, bean2 or bean3, depending upon from where the popup is called) in question. How do I achieve this?

Comment: your richfaces version and jsf version with code snippet would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

1. Add a new bean (`popupBean`) that will contain reference to current bean in popup.
2. Add an action that will set needed bean as property of `popupBean`. Example:

   ```
   <h:commandLink>
       <a4j:ajax render="myPopup"/>
       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{popupBean.currentBean}" value="#{bean1}"/>
       <h:outputText value="Click ME!"/>
   </h:commandLink>
   ```
3. Use `show` attribute of `rich:popupPanel` to show the popup:

   ```
   <rich:popupPanel id="myPopup" modal="true" width="600" moveable="true" 
           show="#{not empty popupBean.currentBean}" onmaskclick="#{rich:component('myPopup')}.hide();" autosized="true">
       <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Cool popup!"/></f:facet>
       <h:panelGrid style="margin: 0">
           <h:panelGroup style="max-height: 400px;overflow-y: auto;" layout="block">
               <h:outputText value="#{popupBean.currentBean.myBeanProperty}"/>
           </h:panelGroup>
           <h:button value="Close" onclick="#{rich:component('myPopup')}.hide();return false;"/>
       </h:panelGrid>
   </rich:popupPanel>
   ```